# How to set up mysql host limitation working with docker container

Tags: docker

I'm setting up a **mysql:5** container (image from docker hub) into a sub-network shared with another container (web server).

I'd like to limit my mysql user to host that correspond to the web server container.

If i limit it directly whith the web-server container ip it's work but this ip cant change because of the docker environement so i'd like to have somethig like:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `db`.* TO 'user'@'container-name'
```

And when i try to connect server respond:

> Access denied for user 'user'@'172.18.0.4'

Where 172.18.0.4 is the correct ip for the web-server container.

---

**Example :**

*docker-compose.yaml*

```
version: '2'
services:
  mysql1:
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysql1
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpwd

  mysql2:
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysql2
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpwd
```

*Up containers*

```
docker-compose up -d
```

*Create user into mysql1*

```
docker-compose exec mysql1 mysql -u root --password="rootpwd" -e "CREATE USER user@mysql2 IDENTIFIED BY 'pwd'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * TO user@mysql2" sys
```

*Try to access mysql1 from mysql2 by user*

```
docker-compose exec mysql2 mysql -u user --password="pwd" -h mysql1 sys
```

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'172.18.0.3' (using password: YES)

*Docker network info*

```
docker network inspect test-mysql-user-host_default
```

> ```
> {
>     "Name": "test-mysql-user-host_default",
>     "Id": "305f4da33e0b79d899ac289e6b3fc1ebf2733baf0bf3d60a53cc94cec44176d1",
>     "Created": "2019-04-26T09:53:23.3237197Z",
>     "Scope": "local",
>     "Driver": "bridge",
>     "EnableIPv6": false,
>     "IPAM": {
>         "Driver": "default",
>         "Options": null,
>         "Config": [
>             {
>                 "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
>                 "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
>             }
>         ]
>     },
>     "Internal": false,
>     "Attachable": false,
>     "Ingress": false,
>     "ConfigFrom": {
>         "Network": ""
>     },
>     "ConfigOnly": false,
>     "Containers": {
>         "133ebd1e6ba485212e5448670c66c1718917650bc217264183c725fb1a928118": {
>             "Name": "mysql1",
>             "EndpointID": "ce89aa1674e9c46fad50b2f36aec8d1eecf2227f597a785be67785ade770fef7",
>             "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
>             "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
>             "IPv6Address": ""
>         },
>         "d67072a5c486752b7018fa321e47ae09fb873199604c2b520f2305968d43b577": {
>             "Name": "mysql2",
>             "EndpointID": "e6b62c6ce9e266d38be383fa6029f378e1ca67a18420dd3f508a3089200c0d98",
>             "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
>             "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
>             "IPv6Address": ""
>         }
>     },
>     "Options": {},
>     "Labels": {}
> }
> ```

Comment: Have you tried with `docker-compose`? Services (i.e. containers) that are started with a single `docker-compose up` are able to discover each other with their service names, so something like `'user@web` should work there.

Comment: Yes, both of my containers and the bridged network are declared in a docker-compose.yaml file. And `docker-compose exec mysql ping web` return a positive respond .

Comment: I see. It seems to be a problem of MySQL's `skip-resolve-host` option which is currently hard-coded in the Dockerfile (see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/154)). TLDR: You could create an own image based on `mysql:5` and `sed` this option away, or you use the `%` wildcard instead of `mysql2`.

Comment: That's it, i didn't imagine that officials dockerfile integrate special configuration... My bad. Thanks a lot by the way, i'm on it since a day :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Comment from bellackn**

> It seems to be a problem of MySQL's skip-resolve-host option which is currently hard-coded in the Dockerfile (see this GitHub issue). TLDR: You could create an own image based on mysql:5 and sed this option away, or you use the % wildcard instead of mysql2.

He's right here the [official dockerfile for mysql:5.7](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/26380f33a0fcd07dda35e37516eb24eaf962845c/5.7/Dockerfile), and at line 70 we can find:

```
#don't reverse lookup hostnames, they are usually another container
&& echo '[mysqld]\nskip-host-cache\nskip-name-resolve' > /etc/mysql/conf.d/docker.cnf
```

I did a new Dockerfile witch remove this configuration file.

```
FROM mysql:5.7

RUN rm /etc/mysql/conf.d/docker.cnf

EXPOSE 3306 33060
CMD ["mysqld"]
```

Comment: Glad it works now. :) I guess you can accept your answer and close this.

Comment: @Charlie have you done any other research on this topic? did you ever find out why MySQL adds that line?

Comment: @St.Jan it's been a long time but I dont think so. It solve my problem at the time so I went for it brainless :p